# How to have a dropdown menu with two, three or more columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Noticed on bootstrap 4 by default I only can have one column for a dropdown menu, is there a way to use grid system inside a dropdown menu so I can have multiple columns or any other method?

That's my code so far but not working at all **(note that the snippet it's responsive so it will display as a mobile instead of desktop if the resolution is to small)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">Header</h6>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">Header</h6>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.dropdown-menu` doesn’t get a proper width here, because it is a descendant of the narrow LI element, and only has `min-width: 10rem;` set. You’d need to increase the (min-)width of that element here for this to work.

Comment: Or remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from the `.row` element - if you explicitly forbid the two flex columns from breaking into multiple rows, then they will take the space they need.

Comment: tryed both solutions but there gives a big space betwen columns and also its not responsive :( isn't a way to autoadjust width with the content I put?

Comment: _“but there gives a big space betwen columns”_ - well the .col-6 classes come with 15px padding already, and you are adding another 1.5rem of padding left and right to your links, so … decrease the latter maybe, if you want “less space” …?

Answer (score 2):

You can also have two to three colums, maybe your are not setting the classes well

```css
.dropdown-menu .drop {
  min-width: 400px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="dropdown my-3">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown Menu With 2 Columns
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown my-3">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown Menu with 3 Columns
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: copyed and pasted your code, the navbar doesn't work but the normal dropdowns yes

Comment: add a class "drop" to it for specificity 

Add min-width prop

.dropdown-menu.drop {
 min-width: 400px;
}